# Use str() command to compose nested string

Tags: python, string

Intuitively, I want to input str(str(100)) to output '"100"', but this, of course, does not work. Any suggestions on how to compose a nested string in Python using only the str() command?

Comment: what do you mean "nested"?

Comment: `'\'' + str(100) + '\''`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `repr`:

```
>>> repr(repr(100))
"'100'"
>>> print repr(repr(100))
'100'
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for.